# $cos(x)$ and $sin(x)$ span the solution space $V$ of $f''(x)=-f(x)$

Tags: calculus

1. Show that for $g(x)\in V$, $(g(x))^2+(g'(x))^2$ is constant.
2. Show that for $g(x)\in V$ with $g(0)=g'(0)=0$, $g(x)=0$ for all $x$.
3. Show that for $f(x)\in V$, $f(x)=f(x)-f(0)\cos(x)-f'(0)\sin(x)$.

For (1.) we have $((g(x))^2+(g'(x))^2) = 2g'(x)(g''(x)+g(x)) = 2g'(x)(-g(x)+g(x)) = 2g'(x)(0) = 0$

For (2.) I'm not sure. Do we just plug in $g'(0)$ and $g(0)$ into the equation we got for (1.)?

For (3.) I'm also unsure. Where do the $\cos$ and \sin$ functions come from?

Comment: For 2 and 3): A general 'element' $g$ in $V$ can be written $g(x) = A\cos(x) + B\sin(x)$ for some constants $A,B$ (this is the definition of $\cos,\sin$ spanning $V$). $A=g(0)$ and $B=g'(0)$

Comment: @Winther: the goal of the exercise is to prove this fact. Not to use it.

Comment: @mookid Fair point

Answer (score 2):

The origin of the last expression:

Let $h(x) = A\cos x + B\sin x$. Then:

- $h''(x) = -h(x)$
- $h(0)  = A; h'(0) = B$ so $h(x) = h(0)\cos x + h'(0)\sin x$. I hope you see now why the third question.

---

1. this is ok.
2. Exactly: if $E(g) = g(x)^2 + g'(x)^2$ (it does not depend on $x$ according to 1.) then
   $\forall x:g(x)^2 \le E(g) = 0 \implies \forall x: g(x) = 0$
3. **Hint:** Try to apply 2. to
   $$
   g(x) = f(x) - f(0)\cos(x) - f'(0) \sin x
   $$